Having Alt-F4 cycle focus to next application
In 22.04 when I used Alt-F4 to close a program, it would move focus to the next open application in the active workspace. But now in 24.04, when I've hit Alt-F4, it won't automatically switch focus, thus I'm unable to repeatedly issue Alt-F4 to close all application on the active workspace.
Anyone knows if I can change back this behaviour as I had before?
